# Is there any tool to generate the ASM ClassWriter code?

Tags: java, bytecode, eclipse-jdt, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

I want to create dynamic java classes, I use a template to generate the source code, and then use jasper jdt to compile. But now, I want to remove the dependency for jdt and create  class bytecode with ASM directly.

The source code is about 200 lines, is there any tool to help generate the byte code with ASM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the ASMifier. This will generate code to re-create the byte code of any `.class` file.  You can change this to generate byte code based on a template.